# Sum of even numbers in 2D array

Tags: arrays, c

The code won't print the sum of even numbers. Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {     
    int row=2,col=5;
    int array[row][col];         
    int a,b; int sum=0;  
    
    printf("Enter the elements: \n"); 
    
    for(a=0;a<row;a++)          
        for(b=0;b<col;b++)          
            scanf("%d",&array[a][b]);   
    
    printf("\nThe elements are: \n ");
    
    for(a=0;a<row;a++) { 
        for(b=0;b<col;b++) {         
            printf("%d\t",array[a][b]); 
        }         
        printf("\n"); 
    }   
    
    for(a=0;a<row;a++) {         
        for(b=0;b<col;b++) {              
            if(array[row][col]%2==0){                    
                sum=sum+array[row][col];   
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("\nequal even numbers: %d",sum);         
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. A tip for posting code. Put 4 spaces in front of every code line. You can also select the code and press the `{}` symbol at the top of the input box

Comment: Alternatively: You can place three backticks before and after code blocks, then you don't have to additionally indent every line (especially interesting for longer code blocks that you might have copied).

Comment: Off-topic: Get used to *always* check the result of functions of the `scanf` family. These functions return the number of items successfully scanned, so in your case it should be: `if(scanf("%d", &array[a][b]) == 1) { /* OK */ } else { /* error handling required! */ }`. Alternatively, if you want to go on in any case, you might do this in a while loop: `while(scanf(...) != 1) { /* print error message, cleanup input stream */ }`.

Answer (score 3):

```c
if (array[row][col] % 2 == 0) {
    sum = sum + array[row][col];
```

You have to get `array[a][b]` to calculate modulo, not `array[row][col]`.

```c
if (array[a][b] % 2 == 0) {
    sum = sum + array[a][b];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in at the place, where you check for even and uneven numbers.

```
    for(a=0;a<row;a++) { 

    for(b=0;b<col;b++) {      

        if(array[row][col]%2==0){
```

You are trying to iterate over all elements of the array, however in the if condition you are always accessing memory out-of-bounds of the array (max indexes are [row-1] and [col-1]. Replace `[row][col]` with `[a][b]`